# PHP file uploads: is it safe for me to store any files as long as it can't be accessed?

Tags: php, file, security, upload

I understand the security flaw in the following situation:

User uploads `filemanager.php` and my script moves it to the web accessible `uploads` folder. User then visits `http://example.com/uploads/filemanager.php` and has access to my files.

However, if the `uploads` folder is stored outside of the publicly accessible web folder (i.e. `/var/uploads`) and the files are never served directly, is it safe to allow any file?

For example to download, the user would go to `http://example.com/download.php?id=123` and PHP would look up the file location assosciated with the ID, then directly output the contents of the file as a download (setting headers to force a download and then using `readfile()`)

I understand that viruses could be uploaded, etc. but would the server itself be protected from dangerous files this way?

Comment: Fundamentally all you have to do is make your web server *not* execute any file within the folder. It's entirely configurable whether your web server runs a file through PHP or not, regardless of its extension. To answer your question: yes, it's safe, but just for this purpose it's too much overhead and could be done simpler through appropriate web server tweaking.